# Trying to boot a USB from Ubuntu, it crashed, and remained in read-only mode, how do I disable it?

Tags: boot, usb, read-only

I have tried many things, but they don't work, I don't know what to do.

The name of the USB is sdb.

GParted don't work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have created a bootable live Ubuntu USB. This USB drive can only be used for booting and installing Ubuntu. You can't use it as a normal USB unless you reformat it. If Ubuntu crashes, it may be because the ISO file was corrupted. Download and start again.

Comment: I've tried but couldn't format

Comment: How did you try to reformat it? I’ve found sometimes gparted works when disks doesn’t, for example. If you can’t format it at all (try gparted / disks / windows tools if you have a windows machine), it is probably a hardware failure.

Comment: I tried all of them, and nothing, I use ubuntu.

Comment: @Michael-Liendo, What do want to do: 1. Create and run a live Ubuntu system in the USB pendrive? or 2. Convert the USB pendrive to a data drive (to store data and maybe transfer the data between computers? -- If you run Ubuntu in your computer, and want to create a live Ubuntu system, please use the Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator (you need not format the drive before). Otherwise, to make it a data drive, please use Gparted. -- If still problems, [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) may help you.

Comment: Search this site for usb read-only iso9660.  The ISO9660 filesystem is not ext4, file checks must be of type iso9660.  Filesystem iso9660 is read-only, so fsck should fail anyway, nothing may be cjhanged/fixed.  A USB may be with a partition table or without. With a pt, (example device sdb) the filesystem is on /dev/sdb1, without it is on /dev/sdb.  Some tools get confused without a pt. Sometimes, erasing the first 512 bytes will allow a clean start on devices without a pt (dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb).  Normal usage is to have a pt, but a CDROM or USB emulating a CDROM doesn't.